# Convert BigInteger to String using Base64 and reverse the result

Tags: java, base64

I try to convert BigInteger to a string using Base64 and check the reversibility :

This case works fine :

- Check A1 : `"999999999"` => `"O5rJ/w=="`
- Check B1 : `"O5rJ/w=="`  => `"999999999"`

but this case doesn't :

- Check B2 : `"//////"` => `"4294967295"`
- Check A2 : `"4294967295"` => `"/////w"` instead of `"//////"`

I'm using Java 8 and `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

```java
@Test
public void testDecimalToBase64()
{
    final String encodedMaxDec = new String(Base64.encodeInteger(new BigInteger("999999999")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Assert.assertEquals("Check A1", "O5rJ/w==", encodedMaxDec);

    final String encodedMaxB64 = new String(Base64.encodeInteger(new BigInteger("4294967295")), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Assert.assertEquals("Check A2", "//////", encodedMaxB64);
}

@Test
public void testBase64ToDecimal()
{
    final BigInteger decodedMaxDec = Base64.decodeInteger(new String("O5rJ/w==").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Assert.assertEquals("Check B1", "999999999", decodedMaxDec.toString());

    final BigInteger decodedMaxB64 = Base64.decodeInteger(new String("//////").getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Assert.assertEquals("Check B2", "4294967295", decodedMaxB64.toString());

}
```

If anyone has an idea, thank you for helping me ;-)

Comment: I am using Java 8 and I do not see any encodeInteger() or decodeInteger() method for `Base64` (I assume it refers to the class is `java.utils.Base64`). Would you please specify which version of Java you have?

Comment: Hi, I'm using java 8 and `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`

Comment: Try setting your character encoding to StandardCharsets.US_ASCII as that's the standard character set for base64.

Comment: Also, aren't you getting the bytes from a non-base64 encoded string in the second method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The base64 encoding of a `BitInteger`'s bytes when representing `4294967295` isn't `//////`.

I'm assuming that because every integer in Java is signed the `BigInteger` sticks an additional byte on the front to indicate whether the number is positive or negative.

Therefore this code...

`byte[] bigIntegerBytes = BigInteger.valueOf(4294967295l).toByteArray();`

.. returns a 5 byte array and you have the following bytes:

`000000000 11111111 11111111 11111111 1111111`

If you base64 encode that you get `AP////8=`

If what you want to do is base64 encode a `BigInteger` representing `4294967295` and then decode it back again, this should do it.

```
Base64.Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

byte[] bigIntegerBytes = BigInteger.valueOf(4294967295l).toByteArray();
String base64EncodedBigIntegerBytes = encoder.encodeToString(bigIntegerBytes);
System.out.println(base64EncodedBigIntegerBytes);

byte[] decodedBigIntegerBytes = decoder.decode(base64EncodedBigIntegerBytes);
BigInteger decodedBigInteger = new BigInteger(decodedBigIntegerBytes);
System.out.println(decodedBigInteger);
```